# Is it unconventional to construct objects this way? (Several questions about the same constructor)

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, constructor, static

I recon a `Thread` object could normally be created and kept track of in this fashion:

```
ArrayList<MyThreadClass> threads = new ArrayList<>();

MyThreadClass myThread = new Thread();
myThread.start();
threads.add(myThread);
```

But instead of doing all that *explicitly*, how about adding it to the constructor and make it happen *implicitly*?

I am creating a generalized server/client pair of programs to be implemented in my future network applications and I've taken a few shortcuts that I find practical.

I have created a "Connection" class to keep track of the clients that have connected to the server. It looks something like this:

```
class Connection{
    private static ArrayList<Connection> clients = new ArrayList<>();
    MyListener listener; //extends Thread

    Connection(Socket s){
        listener = new MyListener(s)
        listener.start();
        clients.add(this);
    }
}
```

This class has a static ArrayList to keep track of all the connections and the constructor implicitly adds each `new Connection` to this list and also starts my listener `Thread` to receive incoming network traffic.

I also have a `ConnectionListener` which the server is using to accept incoming connections and make `Connection` instances for each of them which looks something like this:

```
while(true){
    //try/catch blocks excluded here for the sake of simplicity
    new Connection(serverSocket.accept());
}
```

Perhaps I just haven't stumbled over the right code examples, but I very rarely (if at all) see this way of using a constructor to make objects and store their references. I'm wondering if it's unconventional and/or impractical to use either of the listed cases, and if any of them can cause errors.

**Is it unconventional/impractical to:**

- Use the `new MyClass()` without storing the returned reference?
- Add instance to a List using the `this` keyword from it's constructor?
- Start a `Thread` from within it's (child's) constructor?
- Can it cause problems to reference an instance before it's constructor has finished? (in this case within the constructor itself)

Comment: For codereviews, please turn to codereview.stackexchange.com. My quick comments: a lot of bad ideas. **static** can be pretty *dangerous* as it can make **testing** of your code really hard. Then: constructors should only construct objects ... you might want to decouple that from "real action" like starting threads and so on. Long story short: you want to read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design) for example. Then you want to practice TDD in order to come up with a design that is actually unit testable ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jägermeister Regarding codereview: I'm not asking for people to analyze my code, I have very specific questions about specific programming conventions, does that not make the article eligible to stay here?

Comment: Naming a class in a singular form (`Connection`) but then making the class a collection of that class (*`Connections`*) is an indicator something's not making sense.

Comment: This really doesn't belong on Code Review.  There are some opinionated elements here, but it sounds like you're [still at the whiteboard](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Note that there is a difference between "(un)conventional" and "(in)correct". You might see code being written in this way, and in that sense it is "not unconventional"; however, that's not to say that it is correct (or, to use a less strong term, desirable), for the reasons set out in my answer.

Comment: Specifically with regard to threads, it's often better to use an `ExecutorService` (a thread pool) than to create threads yourself.

Comment: @Jesper Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I want to specify how to stop a Thread, doesn't thread pools take that away from me? In this case I wanna specify how/when to interrupt the Threads that are listening or waiting for network data, while I wanna wait for other application-running threads to finish manually.

Comment: @Chexxor depending on how exactly you're dealing with connections etc. you could keep a list of sockets or `SocketChannel` objects; you can close the connection from a different thread, which will cause an exception in the thread that is blocked reading data from the socket. You can catch the exception and return from the thread's `run()` method to end the thread.

Comment: You might want to google for "leaking this in constructor"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Use the new MyClass() without storing the returned reference?

This is a little bit strange, unless you immediately invoke a method on that reference - this implies that the constructor has a side-effect; generally, you should try to avoid side effects in constructors.

The side effect here is adding the instance to a `static` list; I strongly recommend against that. This is mutable global state, and can lead to all sorts of hard-to-debug issues, as well as decreased testability.

It would be better to have a factory to create `Connection` instances, and add it to a list of "instances created by the factory":

```
class ConnectionFactory {
  List<Connection> createdInstances;

  Connection createInstance(Socket socket) {
    Connection instance = new Connection(socket);
    createdInstances.add(instance);
    return instance;
  }
}
```

> 2. Add instance to a List using the this keyword from it's constructor?

Well, this is related to

> 4. Can it cause problems to reference an instance before it's constructor has finished? (in this case within the constructor itself)

To which the answer is **yes**, it can cause a whole host of problems, especially if you are using the instances in multi-threaded code. I recommend you read *Java Concurrency In Practice*, which gives a thorough treatment of the problems associated with leaking references to partially-initialized objects.

> 3. Start a Thread from within it's (child's) constructor?

This is an example of "doing too much work in a constructor", which [Misko Hevery has written an excellent article about](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/) .

Comment: Good answer! Regarding the factory I already have 10 classes to make a simple server/client pair that only streams objects at the simplest level so far, and making another class for a 3-line code seems like overkill. However, is the static keyword recommended against for all uses or just for lists of the instances?

Comment: As with all tools, `static` has its use; in general, be very suspicious about anything mutable in a `static` field (as well as non-final `static` fields).

Answer (score 0):

Much of this appears a matter of style and taste. However, (2) through (4) ask for special care in a multi-threaded context as another control flow may gain access to the object under construction before the construction is fully completed by the current thread. So, *leak* the reference only when you have established a consistent state of the object, e.g., at the very end of the constructor. Make sure to synchronize the data structure used in (2) properly using a single unique lock, e.g., lock on itself or the containing class object.

Comment: Synchronizing the entire list would stop multiple threads from accessing different elements simultaneously, so in that case I would have to synchronize the individual connections - but wouldn't it make the situation even more obscure if synchronize everything inside the constructor by locking the object that is being constructed inside the constructor? I suppose I'm just arguing towards not leaking the reference in the first place.

Comment: You only synchronize the list access, i.e., adding and retrieving registered instances. This does **not** prevent any concurrency in using those instances.

Comment: But say I don't want to limit the retrieving by locking the list, and I only synchronize the adding part... What happens if two threads try to .get(index) with different indexes at the same time? My guess is that this won't cause problem since if I got it right, only editing of values can actually cause overwriting and such multi-thread problems... Am I wrong? Can two threads reading the same list cause a mixup? Can two threads get the wrong list items because of each other? I know it's not a big deal since retrieving an element is probably a quick operation anyway.